# Google Analytics with iOS 5

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I'm banging my head trying to figure this out, and hoping I'm missing something obvious.  With iOS 5 the app crashes upon launch.  Everything works with iOS 8.  Can I get Google Analytics working on iOS 5?

I'm adding Google Analytics to a project that still has iPad 1 users.  I used Cocoapods (first time I used it) to set it up and it works fine with iOS 8.  However, I want this to also work on iOS 5.  My app and Google Analytics is targeting iOS 5, so I thought this could work.

I did see the messages below during my pod install, but only need some basic analytics to start with.

Initially the app was targeting iOS 4.3 and got the following when I did a pod install"

> [!] The platform of the target `SalesTool` (iOS 4.3) may not be compatible with `Google/Analytics (1.0.7)` which has a minimum requirement of iOS 7.0.
>   [!] The platform of the target `SalesTool` (iOS 4.3) may not be compatible with `Google/Core (1.0.7)` which has a minimum requirement of iOS 7.0.
>   [!] The platform of the target `SalesTool` (iOS 4.3) may not be compatible with `GoogleAnalytics (3.12.0)` which has a minimum requirement of iOS 5.0.
>   [!] The platform of the target `SalesTool` (iOS 4.3) may not be compatible with `GoogleNetworkingUtilities (1.0.0)` which has a minimum requirement of iOS 6.0.
>   [!] The platform of the target `SalesTool` (iOS 4.3) may not be compatible with `GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.0.0)` which has a minimum requirement of iOS 6.0.
>   [!] The platform of the target `SalesTool` (iOS 4.3) may not be compatible with `GoogleUtilities (1.0.1)` which has a minimum requirement of iOS 6.0.

So then updated my target to iOS 5 and got the following when I did a pod install

> [!] The platform of the target `SalesTool` (iOS 5.0) may not be compatible with `Google/Analytics (1.0.7)` which has a minimum requirement of iOS 7.0.
>   [!] The platform of the target `SalesTool` (iOS 5.0) may not be compatible with `Google/Core (1.0.7)` which has a minimum requirement of iOS 7.0.
>   [!] The platform of the target `SalesTool` (iOS 5.0) may not be compatible with `GoogleNetworkingUtilities (1.0.0)` which has a minimum requirement of iOS 6.0.
>   [!] The platform of the target `SalesTool` (iOS 5.0) may not be compatible with `GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.0.0)` which has a minimum requirement of iOS 6.0.
>   [!] The platform of the target `SalesTool` (iOS 5.0) may not be compatible with `GoogleUtilities (1.0.1)` which has a minimum requirement of iOS 6.0.

Comment: What part of `minimum requirement of iOS7` do you not understand?

Comment: You may want to look for a previous version of GAnalitics

Comment: I am meeting the requirement for GoogleAnalytics (3.12.0), but I'm not understanding what I need to meet just to keep it from crashing.  If I don't get full analytics features that ok.  I was also looking at googles documentation, but I seem to be unable to find iOS level support.

Comment: Make the framework optional